# How to avoid a lwuit application restarting after being minimized in java-me

Tags: java-me, mobile-phones, lwuit

I've created an application with lwuit on java-me, however, each time the user receives a phone call the applications is minimized and when the user restores it, the first Form is shown again (a splash form). How can I avoid the application from starting again?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding onHideNotify() and onShowNotify(), In hideNotify, store the last shown form to a variable and display that in onShowNotify()